# CSS Rendering my title incorrectly on small width devices (iPhone SE, etc)

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am creating a site for a home inspector. I am getting this weird CSS issue that I can't figure out.

Steps To Reproduce

1. Launch site as an iPhone/Android in Portrait Mode (iPhone 8 or iPhone SE) (Max Width: 400). (On the iPhone 8 Plus, the last letter overlaps the info button)
2. The name of the company is below the NavBar (when it should be in the white space)

Website with issue: http://oneorangetree.com/index.html

[image: iPad CSS issue]
[image: iPhone 8 Plus Portrait CSS Issue]
[image: iPad mini]
[image: iPhone SE CSS Issue]

*there maybe other issues that I have not discovered yet

I could paste my CSS file but I think it has something to do with .brand-name

```
@media(min-width:1400px){
    .rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-static .rd-navbar-brand .brand-logo{
        width:57px;
        height:57px
    }
    .rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-static .rd-navbar-brand .brand-name{
        margin-left:10px
    }
    .rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-static .rd-navbar-brand .brand-name span:nth-child(1){
        font-size:54px;
        line-height:38px
    }
    .rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-static .rd-navbar-brand .brand-name span:nth-child(2){
        margin-top:9px;
        font-size:14px;
        line-height:10px
    }
}

.rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-static.rd-navbar--is-stuck .rd-navbar-brand .brand-logo,.rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-static.rd-navbar--is-clone .rd-navbar-brand .brand-logo{
    width:34px;
    height:34px
}
.rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-static.rd-navbar--is-stuck .rd-navbar-brand .brand-name,.rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-static.rd-navbar--is-clone .rd-navbar-brand .brand-name{
    margin-left:6px
}
.rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-static.rd-navbar--is-stuck .rd-navbar-brand .brand-name span:nth-child(1),.rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-static.rd-navbar--is-clone .rd-navbar-brand .brand-name span:nth-child(1){
    font-size:32px;
    line-height:23px
}
.rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-static.rd-navbar--is-stuck .rd-navbar-brand .brand-name span:nth-child(2),.rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-static.rd-navbar--is-clone .rd-navbar-brand .brand-name span:nth-child(2){
    margin-top:5px;
    font-size:8px;
    line-height:6px
}

.rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-fullwidth .rd-navbar-brand .brand-logo{
    width:34px;
    height:34px
}
.rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-fullwidth .rd-navbar-brand .brand-name{
    margin-left:6px
}
.rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-fullwidth .rd-navbar-brand .brand-name span:nth-child(1){
    font-size:32px;
    line-height:23px
}
.rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-fullwidth .rd-navbar-brand .brand-name span:nth-child(2){
    margin-top:5px;
    font-size:8px;
    line-height:6px
}
```

I am relatively new to front end web development.

Comment: try to change width to 75 px instead of  width:57px;

Comment: wouldnt themedia query only work with Desktop class browsers because we set the min width to 1400?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the company name is determined by

```
.rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-fixed .rd-navbar-brand .brand-name span:nth-child(1) {
    font-size: 27px;
}
```

So, the font size is 27px. Unfortunately in web design, there's no easy way to make text size responsive. It's going to stay that size on every screen width, so on smaller screens it's going to overlay other things or get kicked down lower.

So you are going to have to add media queries to your CSS to change the size of that text at different screen widths if it's not to your liking.

For example, at 414px width (iPhone 6/7/8 plus) you need something like this to lower the font size to 25px (notice it's *max-width* not min):

```
@media(max-width: 414px) {
    .rd-navbar-default .rd-navbar-fixed .rd-navbar-brand .brand-name span:nth-child(1) {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
}
```

You'll need to do the same kind of thing at 375px and 320px as well.

As you do this, keep in mind that rules lower down in your CSS file override higher ones (especially keeping in mind what happens when min-width and max-width rules conflict). For that reason I suggest adding all of your fixes at the end of the file, it should make things easier.

Comment: should I use !important to make this override any previous rules?

Comment: You should never use !important, it will just cause problems later. You shouldn't need to use !important at all if you have your CSS properly ordered.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the text size with vw unit instead of px. It will auto resize the text size compare to the size of the browser

```
font-size: 3vw;
```

Use this one with screen query makes it more smooth.